Creating constrained Delaunay triangulations for polygons
I have a set of polygons, some of them are connected, but most are not. Some of them are convex, some are not.
Now I want to build a navigation mesh based on the polygons, and I find most of the libraries either take points as input like d3.js or take polygon as input like poly2tri.js.
Extracting the vertexes for the polygon came to mind at first, however for concave polygon, the generated triangles may be out of the origin polygon. Also, these libraries support only the Cartesian coordinate system.
So I wonder if any JS/Java libraries support generating triangles by polygon with geographic coordinate support?

Maybe worth to have a look into: https://turfjs.org/docs/#triangleGrid; Also looks promising https://github.com/x6ud/poly-partition-js

In the java world JTS has a ConformingDelaunayTriangulationBuilder and other variants that should do what you want

@BerndLoigge turf does not support delaunay
